# Unity StopCoroutine not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a method to start a coroutine, and should stop it and reset some things before starting it again.

```
private Coroutine wholeTutorialRoutine;

public void RunWholeTutorial()
{
    tutorialText.text = "";
    StopAllCoroutines();

    if(wholeTutorialRoutine != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(wholeTutorialRoutine);
    }

    wholeTutorialRoutine = StartCoroutine(WholeTutorial());

}

private IEnumerator WholeTutorial()
{
    // Wait until after we are done showing this dialouge
    yield return StartCoroutine(ShowDialougForSeconds("tap_to_kill", 5f));

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);

    yield return StartCoroutine(ShowDialougForSeconds("larger_enemies", 5f));

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);

    yield return StartCoroutine(ShowDialougForSeconds("press_button", 7f));

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    yield return StartCoroutine(ShowDialougForSeconds("button_colors", 5f));
}

private IEnumerator ShowDialougForSeconds(string diagID, float time)
{
    SetText(diagID);

    tutorialText.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("FadeIn");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

    tutorialText.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("FadeOut");
}
```

`wholeTutorialRoutine` is a private field of type `Coroutine`.

I feel like there is something funky happening with those `WaitForSeconds` calls, but I am not quite sure what.

`RunWholeTutorial()` is hooked up to a button, so I want to stop the current tutorial, and start again if the user presses it over and over again.

What happens currently seems to be that the coroutines run on top of one another.

Comment: Have you tried changing the call to StopAllCoroutines under the if statment?

Comment: Yes I have, that doesn't change anything

Comment: Remove the `StopAllCoroutines` and see what happens. It would be good to show how `wholeTutorialRoutine` is declared

Comment: `wholeTutorialRoutine = StartCoroutine(WholeTutorial());`

7 lines down

Comment: I asked how it is declared not how it is initialized. Again what what happens when you remove StopAllCoroutines ?

Comment: Nothing changes when I remove `StopAllCoroutines`

Edited to show declaration at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IEnumerator` instead of `Coroutine` to store the instance of the `RunWholeTutorial` coroutine function **once** in the `Start` function. You can then be able to start and stop it with that `IEnumerator` variable.

```
private IEnumerator wholeTutorialRoutine;

void Start()
{
    wholeTutorialRoutine = WholeTutorial();
}

public void RunWholeTutorial()
{
    tutorialText.text = "";

    if (wholeTutorialRoutine != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(wholeTutorialRoutine);
    }

    StartCoroutine(wholeTutorialRoutine);
}

private IEnumerator WholeTutorial()
{
    // Wait until after we are done showing this dialouge
    yield return StartCoroutine(ShowDialougForSeconds("tap_to_kill", 5f));

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);

    yield return StartCoroutine(ShowDialougForSeconds("larger_enemies", 5f));

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);

    yield return StartCoroutine(ShowDialougForSeconds("press_button", 7f));

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    yield return StartCoroutine(ShowDialougForSeconds("button_colors", 5f));
}

private IEnumerator ShowDialougForSeconds(string diagID, float time)
{
    SetText(diagID);

    tutorialText.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("FadeIn");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

    tutorialText.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("FadeOut");
}
```

Comment: This works partially.. `RunWholeTutorial` is hooked up to a button, and every time you press the button it just skips to the next step in the `WholeTutorial` routine. 

For example, if the "tap_to_kill" step just happened, then you press the button twice, it will automatically skip to the "larger_enemies" step, instead of starting over again from the beginning.

Comment: @BenjaFriend to start over at the beginning you need to do another  `wholeTutorialRoutine = WholeTutorial();` call  after the `StopCoroutine(wholeTutorialRoutine);` line to reset the enumerator